# Rebuild screen when going back in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

On screen 1 I have:

```
Text(getTotalPrice().toStringAsFixed(2) + '€')
```

and

```
double getTotalPrice() {
    double sum = 0.0;
    widget.products.forEach((element) {sum += element.price; print(element.price);});
    return sum;
  }
```

I pass the list products to the screen 2 where I add elements to the list, but when I go back the text widget doesn't get updated even if I do this:

```
setState(()=>widget.productsSelected.add(product)
```

I haven't found any way to do it. Thanks for your help!

Comment: are you passing list through constructor?

Comment: Yes I am `MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Selector(productsSelected: widget.products,),)`

Comment: You have to read about Provider or ChangeNotifier widget